# How do I use lynx to parse a data in http://www.worldometers.info/pt/ website?

Tags: bash, parsing, curl, terminal, lynx

I need to parse a date from worldometers.info but lynx or curl wait not (like a delay) the loading of site.

I tried in the Linux Terminal:
    **lynx -connect_timeout=5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/**
and:
    **lynx -read_timeout=5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/**
and:
    **curl -s -connect-timeout 5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/**
and:
    **curl -s -expect100-timeout 5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/**

Lynx doesn't give the actual data but only responds `retrieving data`.

Thanks

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: I need to parse a date from http://www.worldometers.info/ but lynx or curl wait not (like a delay) the loading of site

Comment: Lynx does not give me the actual data but only responds: retrieving data ...

Comment: Look at `lynx -dump` to dump the contents of the size to `stdout` which you can then process with `grep` or `sed`. See [lynx(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
lynx -connect_timeout=5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/ -dump
lynx -connect_timeout=5 http://www.worldometers.info/pt/ -source
```